# how to remove every nth element from the Scala list?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any methods available to remove every `n th element` from the Scala `List`?

I hope we can do this inside `filter` method and return another list by writing a logic. But is this efficient way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847249/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list-in-scala-having-only-its-index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
list.zipWithIndex
    .filter { case (_, i) => (i + 1) % n != 0 }
    .map { case (e, _) => e }
```

Comment: That will be ok if he really needed `List` here as lists provide sequential access. But if that is not the case and he just wanted to use any `collection` type for his elements then the better approach would have been to use `ArrayBuffer` and just `null`ify all the corresponding indexes.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh In most cases it wouldn't be an adequate replacement: 1. it doesn't work if you have `List[Int]` or other `AnyVal` (or a `List[A]` without a bound on `A`); 2. you now have to handle `null` downstream; 3. you may need indices of the resulting list; etc.

Comment: For any list of length `m` and for any `n` such that `n < m` this list approach takes `3n` operations. Where as if we were using `Array` or `ArrayBuffer` with nullifying we can do it in `m/n` operations. And `nullifying` does not have to involve `null`.

Answer (score 7):

Simplest so far, I think

```
def removeNth[A](myList: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = 
  myList.zipWithIndex collect { case (x,i) if (i + 1) % n != 0 => x }
```

`collect` is an oft-forgotten gem that takes a *partial* function as its second argument, maps elements with that function and ignores those that are not in its domain.

Comment: This will remove everything but the `nth` element. Needs to switch to `!=`.

Comment: It removed the first element from the collection, for example if I have `List(1,2,3,4,5,6)` , the output it returns is `List(2, 3, 5, 6)` when I replace n with 3

Comment: @Ramesh That is pretty straightforward to fix... This is more efficient than `filter`. And you get only two traversals of the list instead of three.

Comment: @Alec : Thanks, I liked your answer very much, +1 for collect method takes partial function as its second argument.

Answer (score 1):

An approach without indexing, by chopping the list into chunks of length `nth` each,

```
xs.grouped(nth).flatMap(_.take(nth-1)).toList
```

From each chunk delivered by `grouped` we take up to `nth-1` items.

This other approach is not efficient (note comment by @ Alexey Romanov), by using a for comprehension which desugars into a `flatMap` and a `withFilter` (*lazy* filter),

```
for (i <- 0 until xs.size if i % nth != nth-1) yield xs(i)
```

Comment: If `xs` is a `List`, _don't_ do the second one: it's quadratic!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive implementation without indexing.

```
  def drop[A](n: Int, lst: List[A]): List[A] = {
    def dropN(i: Int, lst: List[A]): List[A] = (i, lst) match {
      case (0, _ :: xs) => dropN(n, xs)
      case (_, x :: xs) => x :: dropN(i - 1, xs)
      case (_, x) => x
    }
    dropN(n, lst)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative, close to @elm's answer but taking into account that `drop(1)` is much faster for lists than `take`ing nearly the entire list:

```
def remove[A](xs: List[A], n: Int) = {
  val (firstPart, rest) = xs.splitAt(n - 1)
  firstPart ++ rest.grouped(n).flatMap(_.drop(1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is **tail-recursive** implementation for List using accumulator:

```
  import scala.annotation.tailrec
  def dropNth[A](lst: List[A], n: Int): List[A] = {
    @tailrec
    def dropRec(i: Int, lst: List[A], acc: List[A]): List[A] = (i, lst) match {
      case (_, Nil) => acc
      case (1, x :: xs) => dropRec(n, xs, acc)
      case (i, x :: xs) => dropRec(i - 1, xs, x :: acc)
    }
    dropRec(n, lst, Nil).reverse
  }
```

---

**Update:** As noted in the comments, I have tried the other solutions here on large `(1 to 5000000).toList` input. Those with `zipWithIndex filter/collect` fail on `OutOfMemoryError` and the (non-tail) recurcive fails on `StackOverflowError`. Mine using List cons (`::`) and `tailrec` works well.

That is because the zipping-with-index creates new `ListBuffer` and is appending the tuples, that leads to `OOM`. 
And the recursive simply has 5 million levels of recursion, which is too much for the stack.

The tail-recursive creates no unnecessary objects and effectively creates two copies of the input (that is, 2*5 million of `::` instances), both in `O(n)`. The first is to create the filtered elements, which are in reverse order, because the output is prepended `x :: acc` (in `O(1)`, while appending a `List` is `O(n)`). The second one is simply the reverse of the recursive output.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: it does. `scala> dropNth((1 to 20).toList, 3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20)` as you see 3rd, 6th etc. are not there.

Comment: Yes. My bad for not noticing. I think this is a better solution compared to all others. The only problem with this is that `GC` will be troublesome for huge lists. But why do you need that reverse ? Why not replace `x :: acc` by `acc + x` ?

Comment: If you don't see how `GC` will be a problem, then try this - `(1 to 5000000).toList` simple looking thing. `GC` is the achilles bane of immutable programming in  Scala.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I do not append the list because it is `O(n)` so the overall complexity would be quadratic. Prepend to list on the other hand is `O(1)` and do the reverse is `O(n)`, but is done just once. `(1 to 5000000)` input was computed in a few seconds. I thing GC is not an issue because this implementation actually creates just two copies of the input. This computation could be done efficiently on Streams, without need to store the whole sequence in memory. But that was not OPs question.

Comment: I have tried the other solutions here on large `(1 to 5000000).toList`. Those with `zipWithIndex filter`fail on `OutOfMemoryError` and the (non-tail) recurcive fails on `StackOverflowError`. Mine using List cons (`::`) and tailrec works well.

Comment: @MartinMilichovský : Thanks for the detailed analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution

```
scala> def dropNth[T](list:List[T], n:Int) :List[T] = {
     | list.take(n-1):::list.drop(n)
     | }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach: make a function for List that does exactly what you need. This does the same as Martin's dropNth function, but doesn't need the O(n) `reverse`:

```
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    implicit class improvedList[A](xs: List[A]) {
      def filterAllWhereIndex(n: Int): List[A] = {
        var i = 1
        var these = xs
        val b = new ListBuffer[A]
        while (these.nonEmpty) {
          if (i !=  n) {
            b += these.head
            i += 1
          } else i = 1
          these = these.tail
        }
        b.result
      }
    }

    (1 to 5000000).toList filterAllWhereIndex 3
```

If you want efficient this does the trick. Plus it can be used as infix operator as shown above. This a good pattern to know in order to avoid using `zipWithIndex`, which seems a bit heavy handed on both time and space.