# Drop every Nth element from a Scala Array

Tags: scala

My requirement is to drop every Nth element from a Scala Array (pls note every Nth element). I wrote the below method which does the job. Since, I am new to Scala, I couldn't avoid the Java hangover. Is there a simpler or more efficient alternative?

```
def DropNthItem(a: Array[String], n: Int): Array[String] = {
 val in = a.indices.filter(_ % n != 0)
 val ab: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()
 for ( i <- in)
    ab += a(i-1)
 return ab.toArray
}
```

Comment: You might also want to look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105121/how-to-remove-every-nth-element-from-the-scala-list

Answer (score 4):

You made a good start. Consider this simplification.

```
def DropNthItem(a: Array[String], n: Int): Array[String] =
  a.indices.filter(x => (x+1) % n != 0).map(a).toArray
```

Comment: Thank you. However, your logic skips the 1st record (a[0] - since 0 % n will be 0). My logic a(i-1) ensures the first element is not lost.

Comment: No problem. Easily fixed.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
arr.grouped(n).flatMap(_.take(n-1)).toArray
```

Comment: The only solution so far without an intermediate data structure.

Comment: If we were code golfing, I'd suggest using `init`, but I suspect even experienced Scala programmers use it so rarely they'd have to look it up.

Comment: @JoePallas nope. That's what I had initially (I had `.dropRight(1)`) actually, but as Victor pointed out, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps functionally using `zipWithIndex` to get an array of elements tupled with their indices, and then `collect` to build a new array consisting of only elements that have indices that aren't `0 = i % n`.

```
def dropNth[A: reflect.ClassTag](arr: Array[A], n: Int): Array[A] =
  arr.zipWithIndex.collect { case (a, i) if (i + 1) % n != 0 => a }
```

Comment: I would add `arr.toIterator. ... .toArray` to avoid creating another array

Comment: Are you sure? That actually seems to make it slower.

Answer (score 1):

This will make it

```
def DropNthItem(a: Array[String], n: Int): Array[String] =
   a.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 % n != 0).map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for performance (since you're using an `ArrayBuffer`), you might as well track the index with a `var`, manually increment it, and check it with an `if` to filter out n-multiple-indexed values.

```
def dropNth[A: reflect.ClassTag](arr: Array[A], n: Int): Array[A] = {
    val buf = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[A]
    var i = 0
    for(a <- arr) {
        if((i + 1) % n != 0) buf += a
        i += 1
    }
    buf.toArray
}
```

It's faster still if we traverse the original array as an iterator using a while loop.

```
def dropNth[A: reflect.ClassTag](arr: Array[A], n: Int): Array[A] = {
    val buf = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[A]
    val it = arr.iterator
    var i = 0
    while(it.hasNext) {
        val a = it.next
        if((i + 1) % n != 0) buf += a
        i += 1
    }
    buf.toArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this;

```
def dropEvery[A](arr: Seq[A], n: Int) = arr.foldLeft((Seq.empty[A], 0)) {
  case ((acc, idx), _) if idx == n - 1 => (acc, 0)
  case ((acc, idx), el) => (acc :+ el, idx + 1)
}._1

// example: dropEvery(1 to 100, 3)
// res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79, 80, 82, 83, 85, 86, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 95, 97, 98, 100)
```

This is efficient since it requires a single pass over the array and removes every nth element from it – I believe that is easy to see.
The first case matches when `idx == n - 1` and ignores the element at that index, and passes over the `acc` and resets the count to `0` for the next element. 
If the first case doesn't match, it adds the element to the end of the `acc` and increments the count by 1.

Since you're willing to get rid of the Java *hangover*, you might want to use implicit classes to use this in a very nice way:

```
implicit class MoreFuncs[A](arr: Seq[A]) {
  def dropEvery(n: Int) = arr.foldLeft((Seq.empty[A], 0)) {
    case ((acc, idx), _) if idx == n - 1 => (acc, 0)
    case ((acc, idx), el) => (acc :+ el, idx + 1)
  }._1
}

// example: (1 to 100 dropEvery 1) == Nil (: true)
```

Comment: However, you use Sequences not Arrays. You would need to convert your array first to a sequence and then back to array