# Subtract Seq[A] from Seq[B]

Tags: scala

I have two classes `A` and `B`. Both of them have the same property: `id` and many other different properties.

How can I subtract `Seq[A]` from `Seq[B]` by matching the `id`'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another feasible solution:

```
val seqSub = seqB.filterNot(x => seqA.exists(_.id == x.id))
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work as long as the id field of both classes have the same type.

```
val as: Seq[A] = ???
val bs: Seq[B] = ???

val asSet = as.iterator.map(a => a.id).toSet
val substracted: Seq[B] = bs.filterNot(b => asSet(b.id))
```

Comment: this would fail if `as` is infinite!

Comment: @stew If `as` is infinite I do not see any way of solving the problem. I agree that is the problem of using a failed abstraction like `Seq`.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find an answer matching my definition of subtract, where duplicate elements aren't filtered, (e.g. Seq(1,2,2) subtract Seq(2) = Seq(1,2), det0's definition gives Seq(1) so posting it here.

```
    trait IntId {
      def id: Int
    }
    
    case class A(id: Int) extends IntId
    
    case class B(id: Int) extends IntId
    
    val seqB = Seq(B(1),B(4),B(7),B(7),B(7))
    
    val seqA = Seq(A(7))

    // BSubtractA =  Seq(B(1),B(4),B(7),B(7)), only remove one instance of id 7
    val BSubtractA = seqA.foldLeft(seqB){
      case (seqBAccumulated, a) =>
        val indexOfA = seqBAccumulated.map(_.id).indexOf(a.id)
        if(indexOfA >= 0) {
          seqBAccumulated.take(indexOfA) ++ seqBAccumulated.drop(indexOfA + 1)
        }
        else {
          seqBAccumulated
        }
    }
```

Yes, there are shortcomings to this solution. For example, if `seqA` is larger than `seqB` , then it runs into null pointers (+ I haven't refactored it into a def). Also the performance could be improved to iterate fewer times over the input, however, this satisfied my use case.

Comment: Instead of `acc.take(x) ++ acc.drop(x+1)` you could just `acc.patch(x, Seq(), 1)`.

Comment: @jwvh Agreed. I copied the first answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847249/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-list-in-scala-having-only-its-index But I think you're right `patch` is also valid

Answer (score 0):

That will be far more clean -

```
val seqSub = seqB.filterNot(x => seqA.contains(x))
```